# How can i use callback method on my java code?

Tags: java, interface, callback, runnable

```
public class DowloadEngine implements Runnable {

public DowloadEngine(CallBack c) {
    callback = c;
}

public interface CallBack {
    public void processDone(String message);
}

private final CallBack callback;

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    callback.processDone("'CallBack' func is called");
}
}
```

And there is my main class in here

```
public class GUI implements DowloadEngine.CallBack{

public static void main(String[] args){

    Thread thread = new Thread(new DowloadEngine(this));// Error :Make main not static!!
    thread.start();

    //wait a little to see the result
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    scan.nextLine();
    //wait a little to see the result
}

@Override
public void processDone(String message) {
    //code ...
    //code ...
    //code ...
    System.out.println(message);
}
}
```

I want to do all works on main class via callback method but I did not understand these methodology. How does it works?
How can i use these with together?

Comment: You cannot access the `this` reference inside a `static` method (as it has no associated object) - you need to create an instance (`new GUI`) and pass that instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

`Thread thread = new Thread(new DowloadEngine(this));` to

`Thread thread = new Thread(new DowloadEngine(new GUI()));`